# SQL Server Data warehousing Cube - query timeout expired error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, timeout, data-warehouse

We've got about 10 data warehouses built, for some specific reason 4 of those for the last 3 days have been failing. There hasn't been any new data that has been added or major changes added to those 4.

The errors we are receiving look like this

> Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'MOS' attribute of the 'Lv Dim Seats Orders' dimension from the 'Seats' database was being processed.
>
> OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Query timeout expired; HYT00.
> Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Source Name' attribute of the 'Lv Dim Seats Orders' dimension from the 'Seats' database was being processed.
>
> Server: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.
>
> Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Channel' attribute of the 'Lv Dim Seats Orders' dimension from the 'Seats' database was being processed.
>
> OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Query timeout expired; HYT00.

The errors all the same for all 4 of the warehouses that are failing. The sizes of the data in the fact tables behind these has not increased. Two of the 4 are small in size, 2 are larger - it isn't the cause of the issue. The timing when it runs doesn't seem to be be the direct cause either at least not one we can pin point.

I ran the following script to obtain timing and overlaps perhaps one was blocking the other but that doesn't seem to be the case either.

```
select 
    j.name as 'JobName',
    --run_date,
    --run_time, 
    msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time) as 'RunDateTime',
    h.step_id, 
    h.step_name, 
    h.run_duration
from 
    msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
inner join
    msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h on j.job_id = h.job_id 
where 
    j.enabled = 1  --Only Enabled Jobs
    and run_date = 20220929
order by 
    JobName, run_date, run_time desc
```

The output looks something like this

[image]

I am open to any suggestions - what to test and where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Query timeout expired; HYT00.

Means that SSAS gave up on a long-running query.  So troubleshoot the long-running queries on the data source or increase the [ExternalCommandTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/server-properties/general-properties?view=asallproducts-allversions#externalcommandtimeout).